# Polyline doesn't appear in glass://map image

Tags: google-mirror-api

The glass docs made it look so easy!

I can get my map drawn with start and end points, but the polyline to connect the two isn't getting rendered.

Here's a simple one:

glass://map?w=240&h=360&marker=0;28.036352,-82.422457&marker=1;28.044039,-82.421721&polyline=28.036352,-82.422457,28.044039,-82.421721

After a night and a day of throwing everything at it, still no joy. I must be Doing it Wrong(tm) ... I hope someone sees a problem hidden in plain sight (at least to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon right after `polyline=`. Here's the corrected URL:

```
glass://map?w=240&h=360&marker=0;28.036352,-82.422457&marker=1;28.044039,-82.421721&polyline=;28.036352,-82.422457,28.044039,-82.421721
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/location#rendering_maps_on_timeline_cards) says

> Each polyline consists of a width and color followed by the vertices in the polyline. For example: `polyline=8,ffff0000;47.6,-122.34,47.62,-122.40` specifies an 8-pixel wide red line between (`47.6,-122.34`) and (`47.62,-122.40`).

The proper format for a 2-point polyline is therefore:

```
polyline=WIDTH_IN_PIXELS, COLOR_IN_HEX; START_POINT_LAT, START_POINT_LONG, END_POINT_LAT, END_POINT_LONG,
```

You need to specify the semicolon to denote the end of the width, color tuple.

Comment: I knew it was something small I'd missed. Thanks for your sharp eyes!